# .ajaxStart() and .ajaxStop() not firing after first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

here's what I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //stuff
}).ajaxSend(function() {
    $('.overlay').show();
}).ajaxStop(function() {
    $('.overlay').fadeOut();
});
```

The problem I am having is that the first time I trigger an ajax action it works perfectly, but not any time after that.  I have to reload the page for the ajaxSend/Stop to work again.  So say I load a page, click 'load more' to ajax load content, the overlay shows up no problem.  but then I click it a second time, everything works fine except the modal doesn't show up this time or any time after.

any ideas?

Comment: Instead of `document`, try `"body"`. I'm not sure that will fix it, but it's worth a try

Comment: neither, see below notes in accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(document).ready` will only be called once - when the DOM is loaded. This won't work when loading data via ajax.

Two options:

First, if you can identify the div using its id that you are loading as part of your ajax page load, then you can do (edited):

```
$('.overlay').ajaxSend(function() { 
                                       $(this).show(); });
$('.overlay').ajaxStop(function() { 
                                       $(this).fadeOut(); });
```

Alternatively, you could forego `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop` altogether, and trigger them as you click the "Load More" link e.g. something like:

```
$("a").click(function(){
   var url = $(this).attr('href');
   $(".overlay").show("fast", function(){
       $("#targetdiv").load(url + " #div_id", {}, function(){
          $(".overlay").fadeOut();
       })
   })
   return false;
});
```

Comment: Hmm... the problem ajax doesn't always fire on click and the div that it loads content into isn't always the same one... let me play with this idea though, I might be able to assign a class all divs that have ajax loaded content in them and then do your first recomendation on element.ready()

Comment: Oddly enough.. it seems I fixed this issue already? basically I did what you first recomended by doing the following:
 $('.overlay').ajaxSend(function() {
  $(this).show();
 });
 $('.overlay').ajaxStop(function() {
  $(this).fadeOut();
 });
Kill two birds with one stone.  though I haven't tested this yet on IE heh.. but it works in Firefox and Chrome.  Also I am not checking if that element is .ready() or not.  looks like it's not needed.

Comment: Two things aren't right here. If you call `$(document).ready` before the DOM is ready, it will bind an event so that it will run when the DOM is finally ready. If you call `$(document).ready` after the DOM is ready, it will fire immediately. Also, using `.ready()` on anything but `$(document)` is incorrect - it's only meant for the DOM - http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: This is a great answer, not sure why this doesnt have more upvotes! Had no idea about ajaxSend